# How to sort out a RandomRangeInt can only be called from the main thread in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My goal here is to make the spawned object have completely random colors. I keep getting the error in the question title and I have no idea what I'm doing, right or wrong.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class EnemySpawningScript : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject spawnType = null;
    public float ScaleMin = 0.5f;
    public float ScaleMax = 2.0f;
    public Color OriginalColorforSpawned = new Color(Random.Range(1,255), Random.Range(1,255), Random.Range(1, 255));

void Awake ()
{
    OriginalColorforSpawned = spawnType.GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial.color;
}

void Update ()
{
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Space)) 
    {
        GameObject BasicUnit = Instantiate(spawnType) as GameObject;
        BasicUnit.transform.position = this.transform.position;
        float ScaleOfEnemies = Random.Range (ScaleMin, ScaleMax);
        BasicUnit.transform.localScale = Vector3.one * ScaleOfEnemies;
        BasicUnit.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();

        BasicUnit.name = "ProtoTypeEnemies";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Try Moving the "= new Color(Random.Range(1,255), Random.Range(1,255), Random.Range(1, 255));" into the Awake call;

Comment: I did that but I'm getting unexpected symbol errors. It's nothing specific to public, since when I delete that part the error moves onto 'Color' and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the color init into `Awake` or `Start`. You can't do a `Random.Range` in the declaration line.

Also, you try to set it when you declare it, but in your `Awake` you override it directly.

Edit:
It should look like this:

```
public GameObject spawnType = null;
public float ScaleMin = 0.5f;
public float ScaleMax = 2.0f;
public Color OriginalColorforSpawned;

void Awake ()
{
    OriginalColorforSpawned = new Color(Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f), Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f), Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f));

    spawnType.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = OriginalColorforSpawned;
}
```

Edit:
`Color` takes values from 0.0f to 1.0f.

Also, the recommended naming for variables is `lowerCamelCase` (e.g. `originalColorForSpawned`).

Edit:
Now only effecting the newly spawned object:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class EnemySpawningScript : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject spawnType = null;
    public float scaleMin = 0.5f;
    public float scaleMax = 2.0f;

    void Update ()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Space)) 
        {
            GameObject basicUnit = Instantiate(spawnType) as GameObject;
            basicUnit.transform.position = transform.position;
            float scaleOfEnemies = Random.Range (scaleMin, scaleMax);
            basicUnit.transform.localScale = Vector3.one * scaleOfEnemies;

            // the rigidbody should just be added to the prefab directly
            basicUnit.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();

            basicUnit.name = "ProtoTypeEnemies";

            // change color of this enemy
            Color rColor = new Color(Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f), Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f), Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f));
            basicUnit.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = rColor;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I'm getting 'unexpected symbol' errors for 'public' when I do so. I cut and pasted the line entire into the awake class.

Comment: Keep your deceleration (public Color OriginalColorforSpawned;) where it is.  then assigne it in Awake  (OriginalColorforSpawned = new Color(Random.Range(1,255), Random.Range(1,255), Random.Range(1, 255));  )

Comment: So that fixed the issue but I guess maybe that because I'm trying to edit a pre-fab, the colors aren't actually changing from purple to anything else.

Comment: You never set it. I think you mixed up that other line and actually meant `spawnType.GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial.color = OriginalColorforSpawned;`. If only that individual enemy shall have that color, you need to use only `material`, not `sharedMaterial` though since the latter will change the base object and that way all enemies.

Comment: `spawnType.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.color = OriginalColorforSpawned;
  OriginalColorforSpawned = new Color(Random.Range(1,255), Random.Range(1,255), Random.Range(1, 255)); ` is what is in the awake method. The issue is that all the spawned objects are black.

Comment: Ah, no, first the random, then the `material.color`. Changed that.

Comment: Now everything is white...I have to confess, I don't really understand what GetComponent is supposed to be doing here. I'm just experimenting with the tools the course I'm following gave me.

Comment: Well, you have an object in your scene. This object has a bunch of components, e.g. a transform (position, rotation, scale), a collider, a renderer, scripts, etc. The renderer is for the visuals including a material which is responsible for the color. To actually access this you need to "talk" to the renderer. For this you need a reference and that is what `GetComponent` is for.

Comment: Alright but how can I make my object's colors random? They're all just stuck on white, black, or whatever I change them to manually.

Comment: "Each color component is a floating point value with a range from 0 to 1." --- the beloved unity docs http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html

Comment: Also, I think you most likely want to move the `material.color` part to the instantiation and do it for the instantiated object like you did with position and scale. If all of the objects shall have a rigidbody, add that to the prefab by the way.

Comment: Thank you! I wish I could give you gold or some way of expressing my gratitude but there it is. Rainbows!

Comment: if you set sharedMaterial, it changes the sharedMaterial. if you change material it creates a copy for you. buuuut if you spawn hundreds of those objects, you also create hundreds of materials. it would be far better to provide a collection (array, list, whatever) of materials and pick from that randomly.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that tbh. I'll work up to it later. Also it seems that when the object's color is randomized, it randomizes the color for ALL the objects on the screen that were spawned. Not ideal but there it is.

Comment: @H3770VV027D oh wait, i just read over the code again. thats not the issue. you change the color of the prefab in awake, not the instantiated gameobjects. you need to get the Renderer component of the newly instantiated gameobject. in your case try, `basicUnit.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = new Color(Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f), Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f), Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f));`. The thing with materials still sticks, each time you create a new one, if you create 1000 of those obejcts you have 1000 materials even if a good portion of them looks the same.

Comment: That did it! Is there some way to like comments? You were really helpful in the last here.

Comment: you can upvote it, but its just an addition to gunnars original answer, tick it as correct, people will read on if it doesnt exactly work like they thought on first try. the original answer is not wrong in scope of the original question :D

Comment: I also edited that into it. And yes, as @yes said, there are ways to optimize, but this works for the start.

Comment: I changed all variables to `lowerCamelCase`, so don't get confused about that.